# c++ CStdioFile::WriteString gives incorrect file output

Tags: c++, mfc

The code snippet below causes bad result:

```
void CTesterDlg::OnClickedButtonTest()
{
  CStdioFile  myfile;
  CString strLine1;
  CString strLine2;
  myfile.Open(_T("D:\Test1.csv"), CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
  strLine1 = L"01001,01001,2017-09-22,09:38:18.6,Alarm,STEERING PORT A – NO DATA RECEIVED,,,,0.0,Normal,0,1,0, ,127,0\n";
  strLine2 = L"Monkey, Animal\n";
  myfile.WriteString(strLine2);
  myfile.WriteString(strLine1);
  myfile.WriteString(strLine2);

  myfile.Close();
}
```

when looking inside Test1.csv file

> Monkey, Animal
>   01001,01001,2017-09-22,09:38:18.6,Alarm,STEERING PORT A
>   Monkey, Animal

everything of the `strLine1` after

> "..PORT A" " – NO> DATA RECEIVED,,,,0.0,Normal,0,1,0, ,127,0\n"

was deleted ?
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I use MSVS2015 SP3 C++

Comment: Please put supplemental information in the question and not in comments. You can [edit]  your question once you have submitted it.

Comment: You have a mix of `_T("...")` and `L"..."`, which may or may not be different depending on your build settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a string encoding problem. Notices that the `–` in your source code is an En-dash (Unicode code point U+2013), not a Hyphen-Minus. Change it to a Hyphen-Minus (Unicode code point U+002D) and your text should show up in the output file.

Comment: For UTF-16 compatibility you have to use `CFile::typeUnicode` flag, but then you need UTF-16 reader, it's not very compatible. Alternatively you can drop `CStdioFile` and use UTF-8, or just make sure all characters are ANSI